# How does one change the state of an entity in a Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext?

Tags: rest, odata

When checking that state of an entity in EF and EFCore, one can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(dc.Entry(entity).State);
```

Where dc is an instance of a class derived from DbContext.  The entity variable is an object that belongs to a DbSet defined on the DbContext.

To change the state of the entity, can then do this:

```
dc.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

In building the Microsoft.OData world especially the Microsoft.OData.Client libraries, a lot of idioms and semantics were copied or preserved from the EF world to allow reuse of knowledge.  Unfortunately, many things don't translate exactly.

I am looking for how I can repeat the above.  Assuming dc is as instance of the Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext and entity is part of an EntitySet that resolves on the dc. We can do the following to change the state:

```
Console.WriteLine(dc.GetEntityDescriptor(entity).State);
```

But I cannot modify this state directly as below:

```
dc.GetEntityDescriptor(entity).State = EntityStates.Modified;
```

The property is readonly.  That means there is some other mechanism for effecting this update but I cannot seem to find it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose you can use `DataServiceContext.ChangeState(object entity, EntityStates state)`. In your case this would look like:

```
dc.ChangeState(entity, EntityStates.Modified);
```

Specifically for the state `Modified` you could also use `DataServiceContext.UpdateObject(object entity)`. In your case:

```
dc.UpdateObject(entity);
```

This will also set the entity state to modified.

Comment: Does the work even when there are no changes to entity?

Comment: @Eniola: It should, though I'm not sure how it behaves in combination with `SaveChangesOptions.PostOnlySetProperties`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have some other questions related to this. Do you mind taking a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129682/how-does-one-reload-an-entity-in-a-microsoft-odata-client-dataservicecontext  as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129312/how-does-one-get-a-list-of-all-metadata-about-entities-in-a-microsoft-odata-clie

Comment: @Eniola, I'm afraid I don't know the answer to those questions. I'm not sure what you are trying to do is possible.